# Create extension hstore

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, centos, hstore

I want to use hstore in my postgresql server running on CentOS 7 but hstore.control is not in my postgresql extension folder. I searched for that and came up with the solution to install postgresql93-contrib for postgresql version 9.3. But when I want to install the package, there is no package available for that. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

CentOS 7 was released on 2014-07-07.
PostgreSQL 9.3 was released on 2013-09-09. You would think it would have 9.3, but nope. [CentOS 7 uses PostgreSQL 9.2](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/) which was released on 2012-09-10 and hits End-Of-Life in September 2017.

Find the [official instructions for using the non-CentOS repos here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation). PostgreSQL maintains it's own packages too. The official packages from PostgreSQL for CentOS are available here,

- https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/

Or just use something that updates more than once every 5 years -- like Debian.